# Flask-SocketIO to update image dynamically

Tags: jquery, flask, flask-socketio

I am trying to have my server send images with flask-socketio periodically. I am sending the image over with the following code

app.py

```
with open(f'{app.static_folder}\\image.jpg', ) as f:
        img = f.read()

socketio.emit('my_response',
             {'data': 'Server generated event', 'count': count,
              'image': img})
```

test.js

```
socket.on('my_response', function(msg) {     

    let arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(msg['image']);

    console.log(arrayBufferView);

    var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: "image/jpeg" } );
    var img_url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    console.log(img_url);
    $("#img_cam").attr("src", img_url);
});
```

This is not updating the image for me. I see the right data being sent over with socketio, and the data looks right after the Uint8Array as well.

If I make a button on the html page and use the update image line with a file it works just fine.

How do I take the image sent over and update the image source?

Edit: Fixed my issue as I misspelled img_cam in my html file. This code posted worked.

Comment: Please mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my question by fixing my html file.

The id needed to match between the html file and the js file. The code for updating the image works.